# Como fazer iteração com array bidimensional?

Tags: java, android, array

Olá, estou fazendo uma biblioteca para ajudar na criação de jogos e pra isso gostaria de saber como fazer iteração em arrays bidimensionais, eu sei que o array for monodimensional é só fazer:
     for(String string :strings)
, mas não sei como fazer isso com arrays bidimencionais.
Me ajudem por favor!
Edit1:
Acho que minha pergunta não ficou clara, erro meu, obrigado pela ajuda.
Eu criei duas classes.
Tile.java:

```
public class Tile {  

   Bitmap bmp;  
   int width = bmp.getWidth();
   int height = bmp.getHeight();

   public Tile(Bitmap bmp) {  
     this.bmp = bmp;  
   }  
}
```

TileSet.java:

```
public class TileSet {  

  Tile[][] tileset;  
  Bitmap bmp;
  int bmp_columns, bmp_rows;

  public TileSet(Bitmap bmp, int bmp_columns, int bmp_rows) {  

    this.bmp = bmp;  
    this.bmp_columns = bmp_columns;  
    this.bmp_rows = bmp_rows;  
    tileset = new Tile[bmp_columns][bmp_rows];  

    //o erro acontece nesse trecho:  
    for(Tile tile :tileset) {  
      tile.width = bmp.getWidth() / bmp_columns;  
      tile.height = bmp.getHeight() / bmp_rows;
    }
  }
}
```

Bem, é isso, desculpem a falta de clareza anterior, obrigado pelas respostas e espero que esteja mais claro agora.
Edit2
Obrigado a todos, minha duvida já foi respondida!

Comment: Fiz uma atualização na resposta de acordo com a informação colocada na pergunta. Veja se lhe esclarece.

Comment: Obrigado! Muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primeiro é importante ter em mente  que um array bidimensional nada mais é do que um array unidirecional que contem um array unidimencional em cada uma de suas posições, ou seja, é um array de arrays.

[image: Imagem que ilustra que um array bidimenciona é apenas um array de arrays]
fonte: [Um pouco de arrays | Java e Orientação a Objeto](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/um-pouco-de-arrays/#um-pouco-mais)

Logo, para percorre um array bidimensional é necessário um laços encadeado ou recursão.

**Percorrendo arrays bidimensionais com laço encadeado:**
Ao fazer um laço simples, a cada interação, você terá acesso ao array guardado na respectiva posição do array iterado. Se fizermos analogia a uma matriz, seria com obter cada uma das linhas de uma matriz a cada interação. Feito isso precisamos de um segundo laço dentro do primeiro para percorrer o array mais interno e assim acessar os elementos.

> NOTA: Apesar de um array bidimensional poder armazenar a representação de uma matriz, NÃO podemos considerar um array bidimensional como um matriz, uma vez que a maioria das linguagem permite que os arrays interno guardados pelo array mais externo tenham tamanho diferente, o que significa que em cada linha pode conter um numero de colunas diferentes e isso tem que ser levado em conta na hora de se percorrer um array bidimensional.

Exemplo que imprime os elementos de um array bidimencional em Python:

```py
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

Exemplo que imprime os elementos de um array bidimencional em java usando for tradicional e usando foreach:

```java
public class ExemploListaBidimencional {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] lista = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

        // Usando for
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lista[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(lista[i][j]);
            }
        }

        // Usando foreach
        for (int[] i : lista) {
            for (int j : i) {
                System.out.println(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Percorrendo arrays bidimensionais usando recursão:**
O conceito é o mesmo, porem ao invés de usar um lanço vamos chamar uma função para tratar o primeiro elemento e chamar a mesma função recursivamente para tratar o próximo elemento atentando-se para a condição de parada que neste caso é o fim do array.

Exemplo que imprime os elementos de um array bidimencional recursivamente em java:

```java
public class ExemploListaBidimencional {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] lista = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

        percorreArrayBidimencional(lista, 0, lista.length);
    }

    private static void percorreArrayBidimencional(int[][] lista, int inicio, int fim) {
        if(inicio < fim) {
            percorreArray(lista[inicio], 0, lista[inicio].length);
            percorreArrayBidimencional(lista, inicio + 1, fim);
        }
    }

    private static void percorreArray(int[] lista, int inicio, int fim) {
        if(inicio < fim) {
            System.out.println(lista[inicio]);
            percorreArray(lista, inicio + 1, fim);
        }
    }
}
```

**Percorrendo o array do seu caso:**

```
    for(Tile[] tilesRows :tileset) {
        for(Tile tile : tilesRows){
            tile.width = bmp.getWidth() / bmp_columns;  
            tile.height = bmp.getHeight() / bmp_rows;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Valeu, obrigado! Vou testar aqui mas acho que você resolveu minha duvida!

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Porem é necessário que você perceba uma coisa:  Quando você cria a matriz, todos os elementos nela estão null, então você esta tentando acessar todos elementos null.

Comment: Intendi, obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Verifica se esta informação ajuda :

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-in-java/

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) 
            System.out.println("arr[" + i + "][" + j + "] = "
                               + arr[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Com arrays bidimensionais usa-se laços de iteração aninhados.

É comum usarmos a definição matemática de matriz para arrays de duas dimensões:

> Matrizes são organizações de informações em uma tabela
>   retangular formada por linhas e colunas.
>
> Essa organização em uma tabela facilita que se possa efetuar vários
>   cálculos simultâneos com as informações contidas na matriz.
>
> A matriz tem o formato **m x n** (leia-se: **m por n**, com **m e n ∈ N***), onde *m* é o número de *linhas* e *n* o número de *colunas*.

O normal é se fazer uma iteração por suas linha e outra iteração por suas colunas.

Alguns exemplos de iteração:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {

  //Inicializa uma matriz quadrada de ordem 3x3
  public static char[][] bidArray = new char[][]{{'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Iterando pelas linhas sem o auxilio de um contador:");
    for(char[] linha: bidArray){            
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(linha));
    }
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Iterando pelas linhas com o auxilio de um contador:");    
    for(int i = 0; i < bidArray.length; i++){            
       System.out.println("linha " + i + ": " +Arrays.toString(bidArray[i]));
    }

    System.out.println("Iterando por todos elementos sem o auxilio de contadores:");
    for(char[] linha: bidArray){     
       for(char elemento: linha){      
          System.out.println(elemento);
       }
    }
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Iterando por todos elementos com o auxilio de contadores:");
    for(int i = 0; i < bidArray.length; i++){   
       for(int j = 0; j < bidArray[i].length; j++){
         System.out.println("elemento " + i + "x" + j + ": " + bidArray[i][j]);
       }
    }


  }
}
```

No exemplo que você colocou primeiro você deve iterar pelas linhas obtendo um array unidimensional `Tile[] tiles` e em seguida itera e itera novamente por cada uma dessa linhas para obter os elementos individualmente `Tile tile`.

```
// Itera sobre o array bidimensional obtendo as linhas
for(Tile[] tiles :tileset) {  

  // Itera sobre as linhas obtendo os elementos
  for (Tile tile: tiles){

    tile.width = bmp.getWidth() / bmp_columns;  
    tile.height = bmp.getHeight() / bmp_rows;
  }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Muito obrigado!